# Copy of SQL Server - getting errors in SSIS job for SSAS step

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

I have made a copy of a server that hosts SQL Server with SSAS for test purposes. I have changed the name of the server so that it does not conflict with the original. It runs on the same network as the original.   It processes a series of SSIS jobs that end with a SSAS step to create a cube.  To get the SSIS jobs to run correctly, I have renamed the connection strings for all of the jobs so they reference the new name of the test server. However, when I change the server name in the connection manager string, it throws an error in BIDS. It seems to be trying to access the original server despite changing the connection reference. See the screen shot for details of the error.   Has anyone run into this? I could reconstruct the step or open the dtsx file ion a text editor, but I wanted to make my changes as simple as possible. Has anyone run into this and what was your fix?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sANT2.png)

Comment: Do you have the SSAS source code? Does it have linked dimensions or measure groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply, I do not have access to the project file for the cube. What I did find is that the problem wasn't the job but the Analysis Services after the clone. I changed the setting for LinkToOtherInstance to 1.  I would have preferred not to change the setting becasue now the servers are no longer exactly the same, but it appears to work.  The link below was helpful.

http://markwheeler.com/wordpress/?p=175